# jQuery Mobile form without action gives error message: "error loading page"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, jquery-mobile

So I have an HTML document with jQuery Mobile and a form element like so:

```
<head>

<!-- Include jQuery Mobile stylesheets -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<!-- Include the jQuery library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include the jQuery Mobile library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js">
</script>

</head>

<body>

<form onsubmit="myFunction()" id="myForm">

    <input type="text">

</form>

<button type="submit" form="myForm">Submit</button>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
        //does somethign with form values
    }

</script>

</body>
```

When the form is submitted, I want JavaScript to handle to field values (through a function called by `onsubmit`. I don't want to send it over to another document. That is why I have left out the `action` attribute. However, when I hit submit, jQuery Mobile gives me the following message: "error loading page" (see the picture). What can I do? I need the form to be submitted because I need the form to validate the fields when the button is clicked. That's why I can't just make a button that `onclick` calls a function that grabs the values of the fields.

Any help is much appreciated!!
Thanks in advance!

[image: screenshot]

Comment: add `data-ajax="false"` to form.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could try preventing the `event` generated by submitting the `form` and returning `false` from js so that the js function gets called but the `form` does not get submitted

```
<form onsubmit="myFunction(event)" id="myForm">
                    <!--   ^^^^^ -> pass the event -->
    <input type="text">

</form>

<button type="submit" form="myForm">Submit</button>

<script>
    function myFunction(e) {
                      //^ get the event so we can prevent
        e.preventDefault();

        //does somethign with form values

        return false;
    }

</script>
```